# Kendo Chart Legends

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I have a couple of charts in my dashboard. In couple of charts it shows multiple series dynamically. So the number of series is not definite. The default feature of Kendo chart legends to hide/unhide chart is working fine. The thing I want is to show the first 5 or 6 legends highlighted. When I click on any other the first should go off and this one should be highlighted. And it goes like that.

I am using Kendo Charts (line chart, bar charts, column charts and pie charts) with ASP.net MVC 4

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kendo Charts has some events for legends maybe they can be useful for you 
`.Events(events => events.LegendItemClick)` and `.Events(events => events.LegendItemHover)`

Thnx